# Couldn't set the base images that was captured in a separate script

Tags: typescript, ui-automation, playwright

We are exploring the feasibility of playwright for visual testing using typescript. Now, we have a script that captures the entire pages of an application across browsers, for all resolutions. We followed a naming convention, say .

We would like to have these files as reference images or baselines.

Our task is to compare the actual images with the reference images captured from another script.

Is there any possibility in accomplishing this, as we faced a challenge with the builtin snapshot comparison method.

Step 1: created a script which captures correct images

Step 2: created another script for comparison. The images captured from the step 1 should be made as reference image. Present execution should capture the current image and compare against the reference image of step 1
`

```js
uicapturing.spec.ts
import {test,expect} from "@playwright/test";

test('Capturing Pages',async({page,browserName})=>{
    await page.goto('https://parabank.parasoft.com/parabank/index.htm');
    const name = `homepage-${browserName}.png`;
    await page.screenshot({path:name}); 
})

uiValidation.spec.ts 
import {test,expect} from "@playwright/test";

test('Validating Pages',async({page,browserName})=>{
    await page.goto('https://parabank.parasoft.com/parabank/index.htm');
    const name = `homepage-${browserName}.png`;
    expect(await page.screenshot()).toMatchSnapshot({name:name}); 
})
```

import {test,expect} from "@playwright/test";

test('Capturing Pages',async({page,browserName})=>{
await page.goto('https://parabank.parasoft.com/parabank/index.htm');
const name = `homepage-${browserName}.png`;
await page.screenshot({path:name});
})
`

Comment: Can you share your code?